# Is there a 'var' type in Verilog to store results?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have this register in Verilog...
I want to know if there's a way to store the result of WIDTH-1 in a var, so it doesn't repeat for every port.

Any other recomendation about my code is welcome!

```
module asynchronous_register(d, clk, reset, q);

parameter   WIDTH = 8;

input       [WIDTH-1:0] d;
input       clk;
input       reset;

output      [WIDTH-1:0] q;

reg         [WIDTH-1:0] q;

always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
    case (reset)
        1'b1:       q <= d;
        default:    q <= 1'b0;
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this in Verilog is:

```
 module asynchronous_register #(parameter WIDTH=8, localparam MSB=WIDTH-1) ( 
   input       [MSB:0] d,
   input       [MSB:0] clk,
   input       [MSB:0] reset,

   output reg  [MSB:0] q
  );
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
    case (reset)
        1'b1:       q <= d;
        default:    q <= 1'b0;
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you see anything odd with my code or something else to improve?